# M-V-C: How to get or indicate Selected Items in List box in the Edit Mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, listboxitem

I am creating Multi-Select able List Box. I am able to successfully render items from model to list box. Following is my code:

**Properties**

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> carTypes { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<string> selectedCarTypes { get; set; }
```

**Create Action**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     List<SelectListItem> selectListItem = new List<SelectListItem>();

     foreach(CarType type in db.CarTypes)
        {
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = type.Name,
                Value = type.Id.ToString()
            };
            selectListItem.Add(item);
        }

        Assigning assign = new Assigning ();
        assign.carTypes = selectListItem;
        return View(assign);
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model=>model.selectedCarTypes,Model.carTypes)
```

The problem is the edit action. I have been trying to highlight all the List box in the `Edit View` which are selected for the particular `AssignId` e.g. In list box there are three items: Hyundai, Toyota, and BMW and I select BMW and Toyota and Create Assigning. Now When I come back to Edit View it should highlight BMW and Toyota.

I took reference from [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uFAOcP), but did not work for me. Is there any solution for this problem?

**Modification:** Here is my `Edit Action`

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
     if (id == null)
     {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     Assigning assign = db.Assigning.Find(id);
     if (assign == null)
     {
         return HttpNotFound();
     }
     return View(assign);
}
```

Comment: Post your edit method.

Comment: Done. Check now Please

Comment: Where are you adding `carTypes` in Edit action? You need to set `selected=true` for selected car types on edit.

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: Do you get saved car types from DB this line `Assigning assign = db.Assigning.Find(id);`?

Comment: @User3250 in `db` I am storing values in the format of string. Means If user selecting Toyota and BMW , in `POST Create` I am doing like this    `assign.stringTypes = string.Join(",", assign.selectedCarTypes);}` So the result I am getting in Edit is 2,3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145083/discussion-between-armaan-labib-and-user3250).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting up your models when Edit:

1. `Model.carTypes` should be `List<SelectListItem>` of all CarTypes and
2. `Model.selectedTypes` should be `List<string>` of all selected values

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as SelectList which takes selected value

`public SelectList( IEnumerable items,  object selectedValue)`

in your case

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.selectedCarTypes, 
                     new SelectList(Model.carTypes, Model.SelectedCarTypes))
```

Comment: Did not work. and I need List box not drop down list